# ImportError: cannot import name 'app_commands' from 'discord'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For some reason I'm getting a error when importing app_commands

from discord import app_commands

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vwv42\OneDrive\Desktop\AutoMod\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from discord import app_commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_commands' from 'discord' (C:\Users\vwv42\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check that you have the beta of discord.py installed using:

```bash
pip show discord
```

If you get anything other than 2.0.0 you need to install the latest version which has `app_commands`

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the error by updating from 3.7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).